# How to send data in a combobox itemrender?

Tags: actionscript-3, combobox, itemrenderer

I want to send data to a combobox itemrenderer such that it has both dropdown data and the selectedIndex.
Please note that the combobox itemrenderer is part of a List.... So if the data is arraycollection, I am trying to get it mapped correctly using list comprehension....

THE SOLUTION I IMPLEMENTED

Say the combobox data is in an ArrayCollection var d. I created a new ArrayCollection d1 such that d1 items are {d: d, dSelectedIndex: whatever_val_u_determined}

In the list, I set dataProvider = {d1}

In the itemrenderer for the above list items, I set dataProvider = {data.d} and selectedIndex = {data.dSelectedIndex}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

itemRenderer get data from ComboBox's dataProvider. For example, if you create ComboBox like this

```
<s:ComboBox itemRendererFunction="myFunction"
            labelField="lastName">
     <s:dataProvider>
         <mx:ArrayList>
             <fx:Object firstName="Steve" lastName="Smith"/>
             <fx:Object firstName="John" lastName="Jones"/>
             <fx:Object firstName="Mary" lastName="Moore"/>
         </mx:ArrayList>
     </s:dataProvider>
</s:ComboBox>
```

then your itemRenderer will get Object with params firstName and lastName in it's data variable.

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" height="30">

<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    public var country:String;
    ]]></fx:Script>

<s:Label text="{data.firstName + country}"/>
```

data.firstName will be "Steve" or "John" or "Mary"

If you want to send additional params to itemRenderer you can use ComboBox's itemRendererFunction

```
private var Rend1:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(MyItemRenderer);

    private function myFunction(item:Object):ClassFactory {
        Rend1.properties = {country: "USA"};
        return Rend1;
    }
```

And now in you itemRenderer variable "country" will be "USA"